# (tap) on ionic 3 changed after updated?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tap

I have an app that used to work until last year (2018)
But now I tried to use it, and it isn't working anymore.

I have this code:

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let p of pages" (tap)="itemTapped($event, p)">
   <button class="quadrado" ion-button large full color="primary"> 
      <p>{{p.title}}</p>
   </button>
</ion-row>
```

When I tap the row, nothing happens. It used to open another page.
What happened? I didn't change my code since the last time that it was working.

I tried to use (click) and didn't work neither.

**UPDATE**

I fixed commenting these line on all html files:

I don't know why it was blocking the click now, but with that line, the click as working before.

Comment: Yeah I did that, but nothing happens. The function is fine, the problem is with the (tap) event.

Comment: itemTapped(event, p) {
      this.navCtrl.push(p.component);
  }

Comment: Yes, it didn't run

Comment: Nothing happened when I clicked the button. Even the cursor isn't a "pointer" anymore

Comment: I've changed nothing since the last time it was working.

Comment: Even the installed app on my phone isn't working, and i haven't updated it

Comment: I fixed commenting that line on html files: 
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>

Answer (score 0):

try this code i have tested it and it's working

```
  <ion-row *ngFor="let p of pages">
    <button class="quadrado" ion-button large full color="primary" (click)="itemTapped($event,p.page)">
      <p>{{p.title}}</p>
    </button>
  </ion-row>
```

In ionic 4 **button ion-button** is deprecated so if you are using it in ionic 4 then use **ion-button** only I have check this code in both ionic 3 and ionic 4 its working in both version.